# how make a new array of objects with different key names from another array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want to get a new array with different keys.**

```js
options = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Strawberry'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Vanilla' }]
    
    
    //I want to convert that array to another array of objects like so...
    
    newOptions = [
    { value: 1, label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 2, label: 'Vanilla' }]
```

Comment: Use a map, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to `map` each object in your array to a new object with different keys, like so:

```js
options = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Strawberry'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Vanilla' }]

newOptions = options.map(opt => {
   return {
      value: opt.id,
      label: opt.name
    }
});

console.log(newOptions)
```